# How can I "drill down" into JSON with C# when I don't know the key names?

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got some JSON where I know the key names of all but 1 key. Not all keys are present in all instances of the JSON.

How can I "drill down" and get these key names and value with JSON.NET? (It's the "NUMBER": portions that I cannot predict the values for. The only certain thing is that the first one is "0".)

```
    {
      "result": {
        "color": 1,
        "msg": "Hello world?",
        "msg_block": 30276,
        "0": {
          "x": 489,
          "y": 1,
          "dir": 6,
          "stay_in_spawn_area": 0,
          "loot": 0.0
        },
        "8": {
          "x": 437,
          "y": 237,
          "fromX": 437,
          "fromY": 243,
          "wp": [
            437,
            230,
            435,
            228
          ],
          "dir": 8,
          "stay_in_spawn_area": 0,
          "loot": 10.00000001
        },
        "23": {
          "x": 488,
          "y": 4,
          "dir": 2,
          "stay_in_spawn_area": 0,
          "loot": 900.6,
          "has_crown": true
        }
      },
      "error": null,
      "id": 1
    }
```

I'm simply having a horrid time playing voodoo priest with JSON.NET trying to get the numbered portions into a custom object, i.e. I can't seem to manage to get these in a way that I can use them:

```
        "8": {
          "x": 437,
          "y": 237,
          "fromX": 437,
          "fromY": 243,
          "wp": [
            437,
            230,
            435,
            228
          ],
          "dir": 8,
          "stay_in_spawn_area": 0,
          "loot": 10.00000001
        },
```

I've read through a large number of articles, but I always end up with some type that I can't manage to work with.

For the sake of not embarrassing myself, I'm not posting any C# code... :( It wouldn't be helpful anyways.

Comment: I'll check & see if I can get that to work... I've read far too many posts now, but that one doesn't look familiar....

Comment: Is this JSON you're creating? Guessing by the attributes this is some sort of actor object, maybe setting up you JSON as "actor" : { "Id":8,...},

Comment: Ken, no. It's given to me and I have no control over it. Thanks anyways. The article Matt linked to worked for me. I swear it has to be close to the only post I didn't read... It's kind of messy to use 4 nested foreach, but... I guess whatever works.